# bash curl get request raw headers

Tags: bash, curl, get, request

Hello i'm trying to make the following GET request thru CURL

```
GET http://localhost:80/ HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost

Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16

Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

so i try `curl -h "Host:localhost" localhost`
but it dont work, any ideea where i go wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `-H` not `-h`:

```
curl -H "Host:localhost" localhost
```